# Is there a function to concatenate two header rows into one?

Tags: python, string, csv, concatenation

Consider the following textfile excerpt

```
Distance,Velocity,Time
(m),(m/s),(s)
1,1,1
2,1,2
3,1,3
```

I want it to be transformed into this:

```
Distance(m),Velocity(m/s),Time(s)
1,1,1
2,1,2
3,1,3
```

In other words, I want to concatenate rows that contains text, and I want them to be concatenated column-wise.

I am initially manipulating a textfile that's generated from a software. I have successfully transformed it down to only numeric columns and their headers, in a csv format. But I have multiple headers for each column. And I need all the information in each header row, because the column attributes will differ from file to file. How can I do this in a smart way in python?

edit: Thank you for your suggestions, it helped me a lot. I used Daweos solution, and added dynamic row count because number of header rows may differ from 2 to 7, depending on the generated output. Here's the code snippet i ended up with.

```
# Get column headers
a = 0
header_rows= 0
with open(full,"r") as input: 
    Lines= ""

    for line in input:
        l = line
        g = re.sub(' +',' ',l)
        y = re.sub('\t',',',g)
        numlines += 1
        if len(l.encode('ANSI')) > 250:
            # finds header start row
            a += 1               
        if a>0:
            # finds header end row
            if "---" in line:
                header_rows = numlines - (numlines-a+1)
                break
            else:
          #     Lines is my headers string
                Lines = Lines + "%s" % (y) + ' '
    output.close()

# Create concatenated column headers 
rows = [i.split(',') for i in Lines.rstrip().split('\n')]
cols = [list(c) for c in zip(*rows)]
for i in (cols):
    for j in (rows):
        newcolz = [list(c) for c in zip(*rows)]
print(newcolz)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, check the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way:

```
txt = " Distance,Velocity,Time \n (m),(m/s),(s) \n 1,1,1 \n 2,1,2 \n 3,1,3 \n "
rows = [i.split(',') for i in txt.rstrip().split('\n')]
cols = [list(c) for c in zip(*rows)]
newcols = [[i[0]+i[1],*i[2:]] for i in cols]
newrows = [','.join(i) for i in zip(*newcols)]
print(newtxt)
```

Output:

```
 Distance (m),Velocity(m/s),Time (s)
 1,1,1
 2,1,2
 3,1,3
```

Crucial here is usage of `zip` to transpose your data, so I can deal with columns rather than rows. `[[i[0]+i[1],*i[2:]] for i in cols]` is responsible for actual concat, so if you would have headers spanning 3 lines you can do `[[i[0]+i[1]+i[2],*i[3:]] for i in cols]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything that exists to do this so instaed you can just write a custom function. In the example below the function takes to strings and also a separator which defaults to `,`.

It will split each string into a list then use list comprehension using zip to pair up the lists. and then joining the pairs.

Lastly it will join the consolidated headers again with the separator.

```
def concat_headers(header1, header2, seperator=","):
    headers1 = header1.split(seperator)
    headers2 = header2.split(seperator)
    consolidated_headers = ["".join(values) for values in zip(headers1, headers2)]
    return seperator.join(consolidated_headers)


data = """Distance,Velocity,Time\n(m),(m/s),(s)\n1,1,1\n2,1,2\n3,1,3\n"""
header1, header2, *lines = data.splitlines()
consolidated_headers = concat_headers(header1, header2)
print(consolidated_headers)
print("\n".join(lines))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Distance(m),Velocity(m/s),Time(s)
1,1,1
2,1,2
3,1,3
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I added a solution which is basically your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a function to do it because it can be done like this using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module:

```
import csv

data_filename = 'position_data.csv'
new_filename = 'new_position_data.csv'

with open(data_filename, 'r', newline='') as inp, \
     open(new_filename, 'w', newline='') as outp:
    reader, writer = csv.reader(inp), csv.writer(outp)
    row1, row2 = next(reader), next(reader)
    new_header = [a+b for a,b in zip(row1, row2)]
    writer.writerow(new_header)
    # Copy the rest of the input file.
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```